# How to implement Mozilla's client-side JS / HTML5 pdf viewer?

Tags: javascript, html, mozilla, pdf.js, pdf-viewer

I've been trying for a while to install [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) on my server so that I can display a PDF in a viewer like they have in their demo:

http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html

The problem is, I can't get the pdf to appear whatever I do. I've tried even uploading the whole directory with all its files and sub-directories to my server with the default pdf in place, but even that doesn't show the pdf!

These are all the files in the directory on my server:

https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

Does anyone know the correct way to implement this or is there a step-by-step guide out there that shows how to do it that I've missed? I'm assuming I don't need all the files in that directory either right?

Thanks for any guidance, really need it!

Comment: I assume you have a Node-powered server and when PDF is requested you want to give back HTML generated with PDF.js, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build the project using `node make generic` according to the build instructions on  https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

After having placed the built files on a web server you can add the file query string to the url, e.g. `http://server/pdf.js/web/viewer.html?file=http://server/some.pdf`.

Answer (score 1):

A pre-built implementation of pdf.js can be found at:

https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/gh-pages